# How to change color of bars on horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to change the color of the bars on the barchart. As shown, the bars are white, I would like to color them blue.

[image: Click here for code and image of plot]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the color keyword.
`plt.barh(subset_1['duration'], subset_1['deposit'], color=(0, 0, 255, 0))`
R, G, B, alpha

[docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html)

Comment: "Invalid RGBA argument: 0"

Comment: I believe it has to do with how thin the bars are

Comment: [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colors.html) you can also used a set of predeclared colors, such as 'b' for blue.

Comment: `color='#0000ff'` ?

Comment: No error this time but no change from the original plot. color='#0000ff' seems to work on my other plots though...

Comment: I'm not sure how different .barh handles things than regular .bar, but I'm glad you got it working! :)